# Allocating storage to a specific folder on AWS through ssh

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, ubuntu, ssh

I am trying to allocate more storage to `tmpfs` to allow for my web application running on docker images to have enough space.

The following is the result of running `df -h` on the root folder

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             16G     0   16G   0% /dev
tmpfs           3.2G  305M  2.9G  10% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p1   16G   16G     0 100% /
tmpfs            16G     0   16G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs            16G     0   16G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0       90M   90M     0 100% /snap/core/6818
/dev/loop1       18M   18M     0 100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/1335
/dev/loop2       94M   94M     0 100% /snap/core/9066
/dev/loop3       18M   18M     0 100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/1566
tmpfs           3.2G     0  3.2G   0% /run/user/1000
```

What command can I use to allocate more storage on

```
tmpfs           3.2G  305M  2.9G  10% /run
```

Answer (score 1):

By running the following command I was able to add 5G to the intended folder

```
mount -o remount,size=5G /run
```